# How can find iframe value in Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe

[image]

Above is webpage html code.

In python selenium, How i can find iframe value?

Below is my code.

```
frame = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "frm")
frame = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")
frame = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "body_iframe")
frame = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Center_top iframe')
```

When i insert len(frame), Its result is 0 or Error...

help me.

Comment: What element are you trying to get? The `iframe` or the `form`? And what are you meaning by "value" there?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below locator:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//iframe[@id='body_iframe' and @name='body_iframe']")
```

Comment: I didn't write it in above, but already did it. and fail...

Comment: Check if there is more than one iframe with the same name, and also post the URL.

Comment: I also use find_elements, but its result is 0

Comment: can you post URL?

Comment: impossible.
It need two login session.

I manually login and then use selenium.
sorry...

Comment: If you can, post the full HTML source, otherwise sorry, best of luck.

Comment: I fix image.
Actually, that's all